# How do I sidestep CakePHP to write to specific folders?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, cakephp

I'm trying to upload files into a folder, but it keeps failing and I think CakePHP is taking over the write and try to process it as a Controller.
Is this true? And if so, how can I sidestep it?

Comment: How are you uploading them, where are you saving them, what's the error, what exactly makes you think Cake is involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHMOD your upload folder to 0777.

Regards,
Dennis M.

Comment: This is not an answer. Delete it and make it a comment.